# What is the execution order of this countdown?

Tags: javascript

I see below countdown function not work, but I do not know the
execution order of this countdown.
What is the execution order of this countdown function?

```
 function countdown() {
     let i;
     console.log("Countdown:");
     for(i=5; i>=0; i--) {
         setTimeout(function() {
             console.log(i===0 ? "Finish!" : i);
           }, (5-i)*1000)
         ;
     }
 }
 countdown();
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "execution order"? What do you think this code does? Also to make this work as intended see the duplicate (tldr: declare `i` in the for loop `for(let i` ...)

Comment: I mean where i's value come from? In normal I think i is from 5 to 0, but it does not.